# Python IDE That Runs Matplotlib (Especially Without Additional Configuration)

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter, ide

I have been having trouble with matplotlib running on putty and the community version of PyCharm. Is there an IDE that will run matplotlib with minimal or no extra configuration? In putty it somewhat works (no error but also no graph) with matplotlib.use('Agg') but I get an error with matplotlib.use('TKAgg').

This is the error:

```
Use one of following commands are :: --
'UPLOAD' to upload a file
'DOWNLOAD' to download a file
'DELETE' to delete a file
'DIR' to view the current directories
DOWNLOAD
enter the name of the file to download!!!
break.txt
file opened
file close()
time:  start =  0  end =  1587306325.2672875
time:  transfer_time =  1587306325267.287
file downloaded and graph is shown below!!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file_client.py", line 117, in <module>
    plot_graph(result)
  File "file_client.py", line 81, in plot_graph
    plt.scatter(list(time_dict.keys()), list(time_dict.values()))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 3364, in scatter
    ax = gca()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 962, in gca
    return gcf().gca(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 592, in gcf
    return figure()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 539, in figure
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 171, in new_figure_                                                                                                manager
    return cls.new_figure_manager_given_figure(num, fig)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 1049, in n                                                                                                ew_figure_manager_given_figure
    window = Tk.Tk(className="matplotlib")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2023, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useT                                                                                                k, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

Comment: Are you aware of Jupyter? You can also run Jupyter in, say, Visual Code.